# Multiple recaptcha validation

Tags: jquery, plugin-contact-form-7

There are multiple recaptcha on single page. How to check if a particular one is checked on a form submit of a particular form?

Comment: What do you mean? The plugin should take care of this without you needing to do anything. Either way, you'll probably get better help in their official support forums

Comment: Basically you have to send with ajax(jquery) the response from the recaptcha to php, and then send that to google with the secret key, and then you get if the user is hooman. More on that [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify). Finding the secret key may be a challenge if the form is generated via a plugin.